# How to scroll FlatList to some index immediately after scrolling?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

How to scroll `FlatList` component to some index/children after dragging the FlatList?

```
For Example:
```

As we can see in Youtube/TikTok stories, when we drag the screen the next video appears immidiatly after it. So, I am implementing it with FlatList, if we drag the item below then FlatList should move to the above item/index. So, what I am doing is that storing the currently displayed index and on onScrollEndDrag prop I am checking the position of Y, and accordingly run scrollToIndex function, but it's not working.

```
Reason
```

Because while scrolling after drag, FlatList ignores the scrollToIndex function.

Is their anyone to help me out of it???

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, AppState, FlatList, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import fetchDataFromDirectory from '../data/fetchDataFromWhatsApp';
import PlayerVideo from '../components/VideoPlayer';
import Image from '../components/Image';

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get('window');

const AnimatedFlatList = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FlatList);

class VideoScreen extends React.Component {
    state = {
        pdfInfo: [], //[{id, name, path},...]
        appState: '',
        viewableIndex: 0
    }

    fetchData = async () => {
        const data = await fetchDataFromDirectory('videos');
        this.setState({ pdfInfo: data.pdfInfo });
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.state.pdfInfo.length > this.dataLength) { //We are seeing if we need to scroll to top or not
            this.dataLength = this.state.pdfInfo.length;
            try {
                this.list.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 0, viewPosition: 0 })
            } catch (err) {

            }
        }
    }

    handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
        //the app from background to front
        if (this.state.appState.match(/inactive|background/) && nextAppState === 'active') {
            this.fetchData();
        }
        //save the appState
        this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.videoHeight = height;
        this.dataLength = 0;
        this.fetchData();
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange);
    }

    onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItems, changed }) => {
        // console.log("Visible items are", viewableItems);
        // console.log("Changed in this iteration", changed);
        try {
            this.setState({ viewableIndex: viewableItems[0]['index'] })
        } catch (err) {

        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.handleAppStateChange)
    }

    render() {
        return <AnimatedFlatList
            onLayout={(e) => {
                const { height } = e.nativeEvent.layout;
                this.videoHeight = height;
            }}
            // onResponderRelease={e => {console.log(e.nativeEvent.pageY)}}
            // onResponderRelease={(e) => console.log(e.nativeEvent.)}
            // onScrollBeginDrag
            // snapToAlignment={'top'}
            // onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture={(e) => {e.nativeEvent.}}
            // decelerationRate={'fast'}
            decelerationRate={'fast'}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            // onScroll={(e) => console.log('+++++++++++++++++',Object.keys(e), e.nativeEvent)}
            onScrollEndDrag={(e) => {
                // this.list.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: false })
                console.log(e.nativeEvent)
                if (e.nativeEvent.velocity.y > 0.1) {
                    console.log('go to above')
                    this.list.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: this.state.viewableIndex - 1, viewPosition: 0})
                } else if (e.nativeEvent.velocity.y < -0.9){
                    console.log('go to below')
                    this.list.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: this.state.viewableIndex + 1, viewPosition: 0})
                } 
                // if (e.nativeEvent.velocity.y < 0.1000 && e.nativeEvent.velocity.y >= 0) {
                //     this.list.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: this.state.viewableIndex, viewPosition: 0})
                // }
                // else if (e.nativeEvent.velocity.y < -0.1000 && e.nativeEvent.velocity.y < 0) {
                //     this.list.scrollToIndex({animated: true, index: this.state.viewableIndex, viewPosition: 0})
                // }
                // this.list.setNativeProps({ scrollEnabled: true })
                console.log('h1')
            }}
            viewabilityConfig={{
                // itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 90,
                viewAreaCoveragePercentThreshold: 60
            }}
            // extraData={this.state.viewableIndex}
            onViewableItemsChanged={this.onViewableItemsChanged}
            // scr
            contentContainerStyle={styles.screen}
            data={this.state.pdfInfo}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
            ref={ref => this.list = ref}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                // console.log(index)
                return <PlayerVideo
                    source={item.path}
                    refList={this.list}
                    height={this.videoHeight}
                    index={index}
                    isViewable={this.state.viewableIndex == index ? true : false} />
            }}
                </View>
            }}
        />
    }
}

export default VideoScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        backgroundColor: '#111212',
        // flex: 1
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a ref `flatListRef` to the flatlist:

```js
<Flatlist
     ref={(ref) => this.flatListRef = ref}
     data={data}
     keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
     renderItem={renderItem}
     onScrollBeginDrag={onBeginScroll}/>
/>
```

Then define the ***onScrollBeginDrag*** function as below to scroll to a specific index:

```js
onBeginScroll = () => {
    this.flatListRef._listRef._scrollRef.scrollToIndex({ animating: true, index: [YOUR_INDEX_HERE] });
}
```

yes you should access the element **_listRef** then **_scrollRef** then call the **scrollToIndex**

---

- react-native **0.64.1**
- react **17.0.2**

---

Comment: From where I can get _listRef and _scrollRef??? I only have flatlist ref...

Comment: And when user release his fingers then I want to scroll to next/previous index. If we do scrollToIndex in onScrollBeginDrag it will be the worst UI.

Comment: add your ref by adding : ```<Flatlist
     ref={(ref) => this.flatListRef = ref}```

Comment: Already Done! but _listRef and _scrollRef is not exists.